# Avoid test failure when the remote browser is down

Tags: python, selenium

I am running tests every 10 minutes to test the login functionality. However I do not want my test to fail if the remote browser is down. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

import unittest
import sys


class BaseTestCase(object):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://***.**.**.**:****/wd/hub', desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox'})
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://example.com/login")
        self.assertEqual("Login | example.com", self.driver.title)

    def test_LoginTest(self):
        self.fill_out_field("name", "j_username", "abc")
        self.fill_out_field("name", "j_password", "xyz")
        self.click(10, "cssSelector", "input.freeze-login")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        assert "Dashboard" in self.driver.title

    def tearDown(self):

        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            test_method_name = self._testMethodName
            self.driver.save_screenshot(test_method_name + ".png")

        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: what happens when the remote browser is down? is an exception thrown?

Comment: yes it throws an exception

Comment: a somewhat gruesome solution would be to wrap the call to webdriver.Remote in a try/except, set a switch, say self.driver_is_down, if the exception for the browser being down is raised, and put the rest of the test code under an if statement and only run it if the driver is not down